# Show Message at specific timestamp

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to show a Message at a specifict timestamp even if the app is in background.

On the iPhone there are LocalNotificaitons to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current framework. However, the upcoming Mango release will include an Alerts API. The developer tools are due for release next month and the consumer release is expected around November.

You can find out about the upcoming features by checking out the sessions from MIX'11: http://live.visitmix.com

Comment: While what Derek said is absolutely true, if you really want, there may something you can do right now. Nothing can be scheduled on the phone; but you could schedule/time a Push Notification from the cloud or some web service. You would need to have a back-end service that wakes up at the right intervals (got to watch out for time zones) & send a Toast Push to the phone that alerts the user. Just an option .. not the easiest :)

Comment: I already knew Push Notifications but i want to do this even without an internet connection which is needed for push notificaitons.
So all i can do is waiting :D